# JavaScript class did not function in asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net, bootstrap-4

I have created a javascript function in my aspx page..
below are the sample code,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            console.log("ready!");
            var output = [];
            var yr = 1950;
            for (var i = 0; i <= 70; i++) {
                if (i == 0) {
                    output[i] = '<option value="0" selected="selected"> Choose Year</option>';
                }
                else {
                    output[i] = '<option value="' + (parseInt(1950) + parseInt(i - 1)) + '">' + (parseInt(1950) + parseInt(i - 1)) + '</option>';
                }
            }
            $('#yearid').get(0).innerHTML = output.join('');
        });
        $("#yearid").change(function () {
            var select = $("#yearid option:selected").val();
            $("#yearval").val(select);
        });         
    </script>
```

I would like this function execute in the  property such as

```
 <div class="col-md-4 form-group">
                <span>Year : </span>
                <select id="yearid" class="form-control" runat="server">

                </select>

                <input id="yearval" type="hidden"  runat="server"/>
            </div>
```

As the code running, the javascript function above should be executed and display the " Choose Year" propery inside  as shown above.

I try to run this code but nothing happens to the  property. Any help would be appreciated. Thank u.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to be working as below. However you may be missing the jQuery script so you can check if that exists.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
            console.log("ready!");
            var output = [];
            var yr = 1950;
            for (var i = 0; i <= 70; i++) {
                if (i == 0) {
                    output[i] = '<option value="0" selected="selected"> Choose Year</option>';
                }
                else {
                    output[i] = '<option value="' + (parseInt(1950) + parseInt(i - 1)) + '">' + (parseInt(1950) + parseInt(i - 1)) + '</option>';
                }
            }
            $('#yearid').get(0).innerHTML = output.join('');
        });
        $("#yearid").change(function () {
            var select = $("#yearid option:selected").val();
            $("#yearval").val(select);
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-4 form-group">
                <span>Year : </span>
                <select id="yearid" class="form-control" runat="server">

                </select>

                <input id="yearval" type="hidden"  runat="server"/>
            </div>
```

Comment: Mine still not working. May I know why this is happening? I implemented it in Master page. @hydra

Comment: Did you add jQuery reference?

Comment: Yes, I think it's related to bootstrap class. when I copy and paste the code in another page w/o using boostrap class, it works. but when I implemented it in my bootstrap class in Master page aspx, it does't work.Do u have any idea on how to fix this? @hydra

Comment: Could you share your code in master page? Check if your jquery reference is in master page